# What is the best practice for using the same create object methods for the test classes

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have 2 unit test classes (ATest and BTest) for 2 classes (A and B). My classes:

```
public class A {

    public C convert(User user) {
        ...
    }
}
```

```
public class B {

    public D getD(User user) {
        ...
    }
}
```

So 2 classes methods need a User object as a parameter. I have the same method for generating a User in Test classes:

```
private User getUserForTest() {

        User user = new User();
        
        ...
        ...
        ...

        return user;
}
```

`getUserForTest` method too long. I don't want it to duplicate. My question is what is the best practice for using the same `getUserForTest` for `ATest` and `BTest` classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for what is called Test Fixtures.

You could use a third class with some static methods to create the test fixtures (things that you are not testing, but are using for your tests).

```
public class TestHelper{ //or a more specific name would be nice if possible
 
 public static User generateUser(/*add variables if required*/){
 User user = new User();
   ...
   return user;
 }

}
```